# How to get value of Textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

[image]I have a partial view which is rendering like this,i would like to access textbox value to validate using java script,but first row value i got and  value undefined.how to get  @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x[i].WorkStart value.
I have to validate Start time and End time Value using javascript.

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th>Weekdays</th>
                <th>Start Time</th>
                <th>End Time</th>
                <th>Duration</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x[i].IsWorkDay)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].DayName)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].DayName) @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].Day)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].PracticeStaffId)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].LocationId)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @*<div class="controls input-group date form_time" data-date="" data-date-format="hh:ii" data-link-field="dtp_input3" data-link-format="hh:ii">
                                <span class="input-group-addon add-on">
                                    <i class="icon-th fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                                </span>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x[i].WorkStart, new { name = "WorkStart" + i + "", onchange = "onStartChange()", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control timepicker" })

                            </div>*@

                        <div class="input-group date time-datetimepicker" >
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x[i].WorkStart, "{0:HH:mm:ss}", new { name = "WorkStart" + i + "", @id = "WorkStarttime", @onchange ="onStartChange(this.value)", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control timepicker" })
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @*<div class="controls input-group date form_time" data-date="" data-date-format="hh:ii" data-link-field="dtp_input3" data-link-format="hh:ii">
                                <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><i class="icon-th fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x[i].WorkEnd, new { name = "WorkEnd" + i + "", onchange = "onEndChange()", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control timepicker" })
                            </div>*@

                        <div class="input-group date time-datetimepicker">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x[i].WorkEnd, "{0:HH:mm:ss}", new { name = "WorkEnd" + i + "", @id="WorkEndtime",@onchange = "onEndChange(this.event)", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control timepicker" })
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td><span id="span-@i"> @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Duration)</span></td>
                </tr>

            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: `$('#textboxId').val()`.

Comment: Do not use `name = "WorkStart" + i + ""` - it does absolutely nothing. Do not do `@id="WorkEndtime` - that creating duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html. Its `$('#_0__WorkStart')` but you should be giving them class names and using relative selectors

Comment: Then get rid of all those `onchange` and use [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). And you validation should be done using a conditional validation attribute (e.g. using a `[GreaterThan]` attribute)

Comment: Thanx@StephenMuecke

Comment: I am new for Javascript so plz provide some sample code to do this.@StephenMuecke

Comment: What is it that you wanting to compare? (that the EndTime is greater than the StartTime?)

Comment: Yes Exactly .@StephenMuecke

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116248/discussion-between-dinesh-net-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1):

Your use of

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x[i].WorkStart, "{0:HH:mm:ss}", new { 
    name = "WorkStart" + i + "", @id = "WorkStarttime",
    @onchange ="onStartChange(this.value)", @readonly = "readonly", 
    @class = "form-control timepicker" 
})
```

is generating invalid html because your generating duplicate `id` attributes in your loop, and as a consequence, you cannot get the value using `id` selectors because it will only ever return return the value of the first control with `id="WorkStarttime"`.

In addition, using `name = "WorkStart" + i + ""` is pointless (if you inspect the html your generating you will still see `"name="[0].WorkStart"` which is fortunate because model binding would fail if the name was changed). Finally, you should not be polluting your mark-up with behavior, and instead use [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Your view should be (note the additional class name)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x[i].WorkStart, "{0:HH:mm:ss}", new { 
    @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control timepicker workstart" 
})
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x[i].WorkEnd, "{0:HH:mm:ss}", new { 
    @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control timepicker workend" 
})
```

This generatates inputs with `id="_0__WorkStart"`, `id="_1__WorkStart"` etc which is not convenient for selection. Instead use relative selectors based on the class names

```
// To handle the change event of all elements with class="workstart"
$('.workstart').change(function() {
    var start = $(this).val();
    var end = $(this).closest('tr').find('.workend').val();
    // compare the values
}
```

Side note: Rather comparing the values in your own script, you should consider using a conditional validation attribute applied to you model property (for example a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[GreaterThat("WorkStart")]` applied to `public DateTime WorkEnd { get; set; }` property) which will give you both client and server side validation out of the box.